# after .com slash is missing in the url how can i append it

Tags: php, regex, laravel

here is my array with all urls.
    there are some urls such as http://www.floretmedia.comcontact-us.php where / is missing  after .com  how can i append /.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.pepagora.com/product/contactors
        [1] => http://www.pepagora.com/contact
        [2] => http://www.pepagora.com/contact/advertiseWithUs
        [3] => http://www.floretmedia.comcontact-us.php  // after .com / is missing
        [4] => http://floretmedia.com/contact-us.php
        [5] => http://www.coviam.comcontact-us.php // after .com / is missing
        [6] => http://www.nexevo.in/Contact-Us.html
        [7] => http://www.thidiff.com/contact-us
    )
```

iam able to append/prepend http:// with this code

```
   if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $page)) {
          $page = "http://" . $page;
       }
```

**but dont know for / after .com**   please help me thanks in advance

Comment: you can use regex: (.com)     and replace with first group and /    check:https://regex101.com/r/wS6oX1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use this code

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $split = split('.com', $value);
    if(isset($split[1]) && $split[1][0]!='/'){
        $url = $split[0].'.com/'.$split[1];
        $result[] = $url;
    } else {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

the result variable will give you result with all missing .com/

Answer (score 0):

Although @abuhuraira-lakdawala his answer works. You might want to try regex as suggested by @shekhar-khairnar.

```
$page = preg_replace('/.com([^\/])/', '.com/$1', $page);
```

Disclaimer: This regex is not quite optimal, but it works by selecting any character which is not a `/` and replacing it with the same character with a `/` prepended to it.

Comment: Syntax error in this. Plus fixing the syntax error, it won't do what you want. You're wanting to do:  `$page = preg_replace("/.com([^\/])/", ".com/$1", $page);` https://regex101.com/r/kP7yV3/1

Comment: Whups, sleepy me. Good catch. I used https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html to test my solution. But failed correctly porting it to SO. Fixed now.

Comment: @maarten Bicknese, yeh that too is working but it was not posted as answer at that time, i think it was a comment at that time .